# how to enable BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACING

Tags: ebpf

As far as I known, `BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACING` should be available on the folowering environment:

```
# uname  -a 
Linux iZufxxxxxZ 5.10.134-14.1.al8.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 25 18:05:52 CST 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


# cat /boot/config-5.10.134-14.1.al8.x86_64 | grep BPF
CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_LSM=y
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y
CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_DEFAULT_BPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT_ALWAYS_ON=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT_DEFAULT_ON=y
CONFIG_BPF_UNPRIV_DEFAULT_OFF=y
# CONFIG_BPF_PRELOAD is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF=m
# CONFIG_BPFILTER is not set
CONFIG_NET_CLS_BPF=m
CONFIG_NET_ACT_BPF=m
CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER=y
CONFIG_LWTUNNEL_BPF=y
CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y
# CONFIG_BPF_KPROBE_OVERRIDE is not set
CONFIG_TEST_BPF=m



# bpftool feature probe full  | grep 'CONFIG_' 
CONFIG_BPF is set to y
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL is set to y
CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT is set to y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT is set to y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT_ALWAYS_ON is set to y
CONFIG_CGROUPS is set to y
CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF is set to y
CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_CLASSID is set to y
CONFIG_SOCK_CGROUP_DATA is set to y
CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS is set to y
CONFIG_KPROBE_EVENTS is set to y
CONFIG_UPROBE_EVENTS is set to y
CONFIG_TRACING is set to y
CONFIG_FTRACE_SYSCALLS is set to y
CONFIG_FUNCTION_ERROR_INJECTION is set to y
CONFIG_BPF_KPROBE_OVERRIDE is not set
CONFIG_NET is set to y
CONFIG_XDP_SOCKETS is set to y
CONFIG_LWTUNNEL_BPF is set to y
CONFIG_NET_ACT_BPF is set to m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_BPF is set to m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_ACT is set to y
CONFIG_NET_SCH_INGRESS is set to m
CONFIG_XFRM is set to y
CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_CLASSID is set to y
CONFIG_IPV6_SEG6_BPF is not set
CONFIG_BPF_LIRC_MODE2 is not set
CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER is set to y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF is set to m
CONFIG_BPFILTER is not set
CONFIG_BPFILTER_UMH is not set
CONFIG_TEST_BPF is set to m
CONFIG_HZ is set to 1000
```

But when I check with bpftool, it say `NOT available`.

```
# bpftool feature probe | grep -i  program_type  | grep 'NOT available'
eBPF program_type lirc_mode2 is NOT available
eBPF program_type tracing is NOT available
eBPF program_type ext is NOT available
eBPF program_type lsm is NOT available
```

How can I enable the `BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACING`.  Compile with another kernel_config or something else?

---

`strace -ebpf bpftool feature probe >/dev/null`
the full text is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mingregister/stackoverflow_longtext/main/ebpfoutput.log)

> bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACING, insn_cnt=2, insns=0x7ffcc54a2d50, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=NULL, kern_version=KERNEL_VERSION(0, 0, 0), prog_flags=0, prog_name="", prog_ifindex=0, expected_attach_type=BPF_CGROUP_INET_INGRESS, prog_btf_fd=0, func_info_rec_size=0, func_info=NULL, func_info_cnt=0, line_info_rec_size=0, line_info=NULL, line_info_cnt=0, attach_btf_id=0, attach_prog_fd=0}, 120) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)

Comment: Did you run that last bpftool command with privileges? This program type requires privileges to be loaded.

Comment: If you did, then could you provide the output of `strace -ebpf bpftool feature probe >/dev/null`? That should show exactly what happened and why the kernel rejected the probe program.

Comment: @pchaigno  The output is very very long.   I have see some error log, but I can not figure it out.  for example:  `bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACING, insn_cnt=2, insns=0x7ffcc54a2d50, license="GPL", ...., kern_version=KERNEL_VERSION(0, 0, 0), prog_flags=0, prog_name="", prog_ifindex=0, expected_attach_type=BPF_CGROUP_INET_INGRESS, ....., attach_btf_id=0, attach_prog_fd=0}, 120) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`  [full text is here](https://github.com/mingregister/stackoverflow_longtext/blob/main/ebpfoutput.log)

Comment: Please share the output by adding a foldable section in your original post :)

Comment: I couldn't find a way to post the complete output in this post, it's have exceed the stackoverflow's character limit.  So I just post link in the original post.

Comment: I looked at the output. The one line you extracted above is indeed the one that corresponds to the check for that program type. `CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS` is enabled so the program type should be enabled. I can't find what's wrong.